# What are the relations between "Google Cloud Messaging" and native "Push Notification" from Service Worker of Chrome and FireFox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Like the title, I was only follow the tutorial providing by Progressive Web Apps of Google Chrome Developers. I have successfully integrated Google Cloud Messaging into  [**my experiment to do app**](https://github.com/the-unsoul/angular-AMD-service-worker-demo).

As I know for difference browser, for example FireFox and Chrome, we have 2 difference endpoints (and for sure difference subcription ID). I've tried to curl the endpoint I've got from FireFox but did not recieved any notification.

Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox is using a standard Web Push service, Chrome is using GCM for now (but will soon support a standard Web Push service).

So, for Firefox, the CURL command would be different. You can see an example in [this ServiceWorker cookbook recipe](https://serviceworke.rs/push-simple_demo.html):

`curl -H "TTL: 60" -X POST https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/XXX`

In the future, both browsers will use the Web Push standard.

Comment: Look like this is the answer I am look for. Thank a lot!

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = exec('curl -H "TTL: 60" -X POST https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/gAAAAABXrY0W8KTlsOBqVbvXiqETBPmqahT0ch1_ODoyZTfd22cax_vdsscweHMv7uwi9zb-tfTamOM5gBspSDa0IFE1yMBAo6Gtfd_AAcsdeAb7AzJgj2yCZ3Wwp1nacywFvoZRfyVfIN');
echo $result;
```